# Horizontal histogram won't accept input after the first input (edited, wont print input)

Tags: c

So I'm making a program which is supposed to print a horizontal histogram of the lengths of words in its input. So I changed the while into if so it now accepts more than 1 input. But what's wrong with it this time? It won't print the graph.

```
/*Write a program to print a histogram of the lengths of words in its input. 
It is easy to draw the histogram with the bars horizontal*/
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 30
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
int main()
{
int a,c,i,k,state,word[MAX];
a=0;
k=0;
state=OUT;
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    word[i]=0;
while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
    if(c==' '||c=='\t'||c=='\n')
        state=OUT;
    else
        state=IN;
    if(state==IN)
        a++;

    if(state==OUT)
        {
        word[i]=a;
        i++;
        a=0;
        }



}
/*This part is pissing me off, I don't know how to print X multiple times!*/
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
    if(word[i]>0)
        {
            for(k=0;k<=word[i];k++)
            putchar('-');
            putchar('\n');
        }


}
```

Comment: So is it working now then? Because I am running out of obvious findings.

Comment: No.. after i input then input ctrl+z, it just says press any key to continue.. then closes.

Comment: If I your code in your 3rd part. It just prints - in new line 30 times. instead of ------- (with not 30 but just the length of the word) @r_ahlskog

Comment: I just copy-pasted what you had, but yes there is probably some bug in there. I have gotten home now and have access to a decent compiler so I can actually test this out. But if you don't know what goes wrong you should just run it in the debugger and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your problem right there

```
while(state==IN)
    a++;
```

This is basically an endless loop, it will loop forever incrementing `a`

**Edit:** Ok, part two then.

First off what you are doing with `a` is not what you think you are doing.

I think you think you are using it to count word length but you are not resetting it to `0` after each word so it will in fact keep on counting number of found chars. Your histogram will just show growing numbers.

Second, in your print loop you are using `i` in both loops leading to a delicious mess of some sort.

**Edit:** Part three

I just spotted that you are printing the histogram inside the input-loop on the conditional

```
if((c==getchar())&&c==EOF)
```

This is probably not going to work, I suggest to move the printing outside the while loop and remove the condition

```
while ((c=getchar())!=EOF)
{
   ...
}
for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
{
    for(k=0;k<=word[i];k++)
        putchar('-'); 
    putchar('\n');
}
```

then it will get executed after you are finished taking input

**Edit:** Part four

You have reused `i` as index into the array without setting it to zero, the consequence being that the program assigns word lengths to indexes 30-59 which are all outside the array, that it does not crash is just pure luck. Setting `i = 0` before entering the input loop makes the program work.

Now all you have left to think about is why it prints word lengths one too long, I leave that as an exercise to the reader. *Hint: It has to do with comparison operators*

Comment: thanks man! I updated the code and the question! But now it won't print the graph. What's wrong with the print code?

Comment: Oh! I forgot to type that part in that code, I did it in my previous code but that code didn't accept input cause of the while instead of if. I forgot that part when I made this one.I changed this:         `if(state==OUT)
  {
word[i]=a;
i++; 
a=0;}`

Comment: Now I remember why I have a variable k, it's for the printing so i tried it again in my IDE. `for(k=0;k<=word[i];k++)
    {
     putchar('-');
    }
    putchar('\n');` It still wont work.. sorry if I'm a noob at C

Comment: Well, maybe the problem is that you are printing as a special case of the loop, put the print code after the loop so that when you drop out of the loop it will print.

Comment: ok so i edited my first post again. I deleted my previous print code and, placed this after the loop `for(i=0;i<MAX;i++)
  if(word[i]>0)
   {
    for(k=0;k<=word[i];k++)
    putchar('-');
    putchar('\n');
   }`

Comment: Thanks man! It works now!, and the reason its printing one length too long is because i put `for(k=0;k<=word[i];k++) ` When it should only be `for(k=0;k<word[i];k++)`